# Unanswered Questions

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Very frequently, the questions in the Unanswered Questions section have in fact been answered--either in the comments or via editing of the OP--but there are no answers posted to the question.

- I know I can tell the OP to answer/accept an answer, but other than that is there anything else I can do?
- I could also vote to close it, but often times the questions/answers are quite legitimate.

What are my other options to remove these questions from the unanswered tab?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For answers in comments:

You're welcome, if the commenter doesn't respond, to post the answer yourself.  You can give credit to the commenter in the answer.

Comment: I think it's standard practice to use "Community Wiki" in this situation if you have enough rep.

Comment: Some will do that, but I wouldn't call it standard practice.  As far as I'm concerned, if you go to the work to make it happen, you deserve a little rep.

Comment: Well, this isn't really an answer to make me happy, but it's probably the best I'll get.